# Unusual error when returning list of results from API

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm returning data from a .NET Core 3.X API but keep getting this strange error:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

Here is what I'm doing with the data before immediately returning it after.

```cs
     var bookings = bookingData
        .Select(x => new SpecialTaskVm(new TaskViewModel(x, null))
        {
            client = x.Client,
            carer = x.Carer,
            carer2 = x.Carer2
        })
        .ToList();
```

I have tried changing the controller method type

I expect the data to return normally rather than a 500 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Client` and `Carer` both have indirect references to each other via `ClientCarer`.

Rather than serving `Client` and `Carer` up I'd suggest creating a new class / anonymous type with just the specific properties you need.

Comment: How do we go about doing this? Could someone provide an example?