# .NET Core 3.0 possible object cycle was detected which is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities that are related as one-to-many:

```
public class Restaurant {
   public int RestaurantId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public List<Reservation> Reservations {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

```
public class Reservation{
   public int ReservationId {get;set;}
   public int RestaurantId {get;set;}
   public Restaurant Restaurant {get;set;}
}
```

If I try to get restaurants with reservations using my API,

```
   var restaurants = await _dbContext.Restaurants
                .AsNoTracking()
                .AsQueryable()
                .Include(m => m.Reservations).ToListAsync();
    .....
```

I receive an error in response, because objects contain references to each other.
There are related posts that recommend [to create a separate model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885311/unusual-error-when-returning-list-of-results-from-api) or add a [NewtonsoftJson configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912012/net-core-3-upgrade-cors-and-jsoncycle-xmlhttprequest-error).

The problem is that I do not want to create a separate model and the second suggestion didn't help.

Is there a way to load data without a cycled relationship?

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected
> which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the
> object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_SerializerCycleDetected(Int32
> maxDepth)    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold,
> JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object
> value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()

Comment: Ask it to ignore the Restaurant property of the Reservation class.

Comment: Really you shouldn't be returning your DB entities directly from your API. I'd suggest creating API-specific DTOs and mapping accordingly. Granted you said you didn't want to do that but I'd consider it general good practice to keep API and persistence internals separate.

Comment: "Problem is that I do not want to create separate model". Your design is fundamentally flawed unless you do just that. An API is a contract like an interface (it's literally an application programming *interface*). It should not ever change, once published, and any change necessitates a new version, which will need to run concurrently with the old version (which will be deprecated and eventually removed in the future). That allows clients time to update their implementations. If you return an entity directly, you're tightly coupling your data layer.

Comment: Any change to that data layer then necessitates an immediate and irreversible change to the API, breaking all clients immediately until they update their implementations. In case it's not obvious, that's a bad thing. In short: never accept or return entities from an API. You should *always* use DTOs.

Comment: I'm using 'Request' and 'Response' models (I guess it's the same as DTO) managed by Automapper to prevent passing sensitive information and creating, as mentioned, contracts. Maybe I'm wrong, but DTOs do not solve this problem as I still have to return, restaurant where are reservations (with cycled reference). 
Anyway, thanks for answers ! :)

Comment: "You should always use DTOs" ... well, no, not always. 
If the only subscriber to your API is your SPA client application - why would I waste time writing DTOs if there is nothing to brake since the only subscriber has to be updated immediately as well. 
Best practices are fine, but I do not like "always".

Answer (score 260, accepted):

I have tried your code in a new project and the second way seems to work well after installing the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/3.0.0) firstly for 3.0

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

Try with a new project and compare the differences.

Comment: Key moment here is to reinstalling proper version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 
I didn't pay attention for version as this package was available under the box without any errors and warnings! 
Thanks for answer ! Everything works exactly as I expected !

Comment: Isn't it wrong that with improved perf of the system json, we have to use NewtonsoftJson? :/

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz Its wrong to call a serializer which can't handle cycles, or dictionary types production ready.

Comment: Newtonsoft still seems to be the better option

Comment: After so much headache I finally found this!! Thank you so much it worked perfectly. Using a `JsonIgnore` attribute also worked but it's so inconvenient and no objects would be referenced at all which really sucked. But this is the perfect way to solve it. Thanks @Ryan!

Comment: Starting with .NET 5 System.Text.Json contains the option [`ReferenceHandler.Preserve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.referencehandler.preserve?view=net-6.0) and .NET 6 contains [`ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.referencehandler.ignorecycles?view=net-6.0); both are very good alternatives to avoid switching back to Newtonsoft.Json and keep the performance gains of System.Text.Json.

Comment: This fixed the same problem I have. But, is this an ugly workaround or a must do?

Comment: +1 for @Jozkee's comment. I came here looking for this from a .NET 5 implementation and we're trying to avoid using the Newtonsoft.Json package and keep the new System.Text.Json. Solved my problem, thanks! It should be one of the answers, honestly.

Answer (score 195):

**.NET Core 3.1**
Install the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson (from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/ )

**Startup.cs**  Add service

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

Comment: For more details, check: https://thecodebuzz.com/jsonexception-possible-object-cycle-detected-object-depth/

Comment: This is what I need

Answer (score 111):

Check if you `await`-ed all async methods.

Answer (score 65):

**Update:**

Using .NET 6, there is an option for `System.Text.Json` to *ignore* circular references like this:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
{
    ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
    WriteIndented = true
};
```

*[Ignore circular references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0#ignore-circular-references)*

The problem with `ReferenceHandler.Preserve` is that JSON keys are prefixed with `$`, and this can cause some issues.

Example `System.Text.Json` `ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace SerializeIgnoreCycles
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Employee Manager { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> DirectReports { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Employee tyler = new()
            {
                Name = "Tyler Stein"
            };

            Employee adrian = new()
            {
                Name = "Adrian King"
            };

            tyler.DirectReports = new List<Employee> { adrian };
            adrian.Manager = tyler;

            JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
            {
                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
                WriteIndented = true
            };

            string tylerJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(tyler, options);
            Console.WriteLine($"Tyler serialized:\n{tylerJson}");

            Employee tylerDeserialized =
                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Employee>(tylerJson, options);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "Tyler is manager of Tyler's first direct report: ");
            Console.WriteLine(
                tylerDeserialized.DirectReports[0].Manager == tylerDeserialized);
        }
    }
}

// Produces output like the following example:
//
//Tyler serialized:
//{
//  "Name": "Tyler Stein",
//  "Manager": null,
//  "DirectReports": [
//    {
//      "Name": "Adrian King",
//      "Manager": null,
//      "DirectReports": null
//    }
//  ]
//}
//Tyler is manager of Tyler's first direct report:
//False
```

Source:

*[Ignore circular references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0#ignore-circular-references)*

Example with `Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
}

Employee joe = new Employee { Name = "Joe User" };
Employee mike = new Employee { Name = "Mike Manager" };
joe.Manager = mike;
mike.Manager = mike;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});

Console.WriteLine(json);
// {
//   "Name": "Joe User",
//   "Manager": {
//     "Name": "Mike Manager"
//   }
// }
```

*[ReferenceLoopHandling setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm)*

**Original:**

I got this error from the default POST method in Controller created with an API Controller with actions, using [ADO.NET Entity Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework).

```
return CreatedAtAction("GetLearningObjective", new { id = learningObjective.Id }, learningObjective);
```

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected.
> This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger
> than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using
> ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.
> at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_SerializerCycleDetected(Int32
> maxDepth)

When calling `HttpGet` directly from [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) or a browser it worked without a problem. It was solved by editing `Startup.cs` - `services.AddControllers()` like this:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
});
```

You could also solve it like this:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter>();
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter(new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
    }));
});
```

*[How to preserve references and handle or ignore circular references in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-5-0)*

Comment: ignoring this does not resolve the problem. You just ignore the problem.

Comment: @MuhammedYILMAZ I would absolutely say that setting circular reference properties to null is a solution in many cases. I did add an example with `System.Text.Json` `ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles` vs `Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` to clarify the difference though.

Comment: This is the propper answer for version 6+.

Comment: Good for v6 but with ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles

Comment: Upvoted for the API Startup.cs syntax.

Comment: Helped me in AddJwtBearer for .net 7

Answer (score 44):

Instead of using NewtonsoftJson, I used *System.Text.Json.Serialization*.

**For .NET Core 3.1**

In file *Startup.cs*:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    ..........
    .......

    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
    });
 }
```

**For .NET 6**

In file *Program.cs*:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
});
```

Comment: Perfect, it was just what I needed for .net 6

Comment: There is no `ReferenceHandler` Property in `JsonSerializerOptions` in **.net core 3.1**.

Answer (score 26):

Getting the setting JSON serialisation options on startup to work is probably a preferred way as you will likely have similar cases in the future. In the meantime however you could try add data attributes to your model so it's not serialised: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm

```
public class Reservation{ 
    public int ReservationId {get;set;} 
    public int RestaurantId {get;set;} 
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Restaurant Restaurant {get;set;} 
}
```

Comment: This works too. But as you mentioned, with this you have to update all the models, I prefer 
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);

Comment: That would be a situation where I would lead to think what if I don't want to use JsonIgnore because of other ways to access Reservation.

Answer (score 15):

This worked using System.Text.Json

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            MaxDepth = 0,
            IgnoreNullValues = true,
            IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true
        };
```

Using options to serialize

```
objstr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj,options);
```

Comment: This sets MaxDepth but still does not allow objects with depths higher than 0 to go through. What we need is an ignore

Answer (score 14):

As [Jozkee stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199593/net-core-3-0-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-not-supported/62869060#comment123207532_59210264) in a comment in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199593/net-core-3-0-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-not-supported/59210264#59210264), .NET 6 contains `ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles` in `System.Text.Json`.

This is how I solved this issue without installing Newtonsoft.Json and making use of the new addition to .NET 6 by adding the following to `Program.cs`.

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

Here's a [helpful article on object cycles](https://makolyte.com/system-text-json-jsonexception-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-not-supported/) for anyone who's not sure what they are.

Answer (score 9):

After hours of debugging, it really has a simple solution. I found [this link](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/jsonexception-possible-object-cycle-detected-object-depth/comment-page-2/?unapproved=2319&moderation-hash=a3e4421ef39f669454eef3790e21cc08#comment-2319) helpful.

This error was because of:

> default JSON serializer used in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and the above version.
>
> ASP.NET Core 3.0 has removed the dependency on JSON.NET and uses it’s own JSON serializer i.e ‘System.Text.Json‘.

> I was able to fix the issue adding the reference to NewtonsoftJson Nuget package,
>
> ```
> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.1.2
> ```
>
> And update the Startup.cs as below,

> ```cs
> services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
>     options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
> );
> ```

> ReferenceLoopHandling is currently not supported in the System.Text.Json serializer

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
public class Reservation{
    public int ReservationId {get;set;}
    public int RestaurantId {get;set;}
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Restaurant Restaurant {get;set;}
```

The above also worked. But I prefer the following:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

Because first we need to add the attribute to all the models, as we may have a cyclic reference.

Answer (score 8):

I got such an error when I mistakenly returned `Task<object>` instead of an `object` in the controller method. The task leads to a loop. Check what you are returning.

Answer (score 8):

MinimalAPI use this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
```

Comment: Not working. The answer by Vicktor works though

Answer (score 8):

For .NET Core 6, adding this to **Program.cs** solved my problem:

```html
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

Answer (score 7):

This happens because of the 2 way relationship between your data model when it comes to be JSON serialized.

You should not return your data model diectly.  Map it to a new response model then return it.

Comment: The question clearly states "I do not want to create separate model".

Comment: this is what usually causes it for me

Comment: There is a great tool for that called AutoMapper 
here is good example how to use it
https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/

Answer (score 7):

For others who did not find other solutions working, you actually need to analyze your complete call stack, and see if any `async` call is not `await`ed where it is expected to be awaited. Which is the actual issue in problem mentioned in question.

For example, consider following method in `MyAppService`, which calls an `async Task<int>` of `MyOtherService`:

```
public async Task<int> Create(InputModel input)
{
    var id = _myOtherService.CreateAndGetIdAsync(input);
    return Created("someUri", id);
}
```

If `CreateAndGetIdAsync` method is `async Task`, the call to this Create method above will through the given exception as mentioned in question. This is because serialization will break as `id` is `Task<int>` but not `int` in reality. So one must `await` before returing response.

**Additional Note:**
It's important to note one more thing here, that even thought this exception arises, it doesn't impact the db operation. i.e, in my example above, the db operation will be successful. Similarly, as mentioned in OP, the exception wasn't thrown my ORM being used, but this exception was thrown later in sequence of call stack (in one of the callers).

Answer (score 7):

### Microsoft proposed solution

> Because EF Core automatically does fix-up of navigation properties, you can end up with cycles in your object graph. For example, loading a blog and its related posts will result in a blog object that references a collection of posts. Each of those posts will have a reference back to the blog.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization

### Json.NET

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

### System.Text.Json

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
        });

    ...
}
```

### My recommendation

Don't expose your DB models directly to your controllers, that might bring some vulnerabilities in the future. You can create a mapping from the Model to a Dto class or something similar. This way you will not need to disable the cycle-detection mechanism since it is useful to prevent issues.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this question was for .NET Core 3.0, but for anyone encountering the same problem in .NET 5.0, I found a solution [here](https://gavilan.blog/2021/05/19/fixing-the-error-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-in-different-versions-of-asp-net-core/).

In summary, one needs to add the following code in your Startup class, in the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
   x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer changes the default serializer from System.Text.Json to Newtonsoft and will solve the cycle by removing the navigation property from the serialization!

Order example:

```
{
   "id": "d310b004-79a2-4661-2f90-08d8d25fec03"
   "orderItems": [
      {
         "orderId": "d310b004-79a2-4661-2f90-08d8d25fec03",
         "orderItemId": "83d36eda-ba03-448c-e53c-08d8d25fec0b",
         "orderItem": {
            "id": "83d36eda-ba03-448c-e53c-08d8d25fec0b",
            "name": "My order item"
         }
         // where is the reference to the order?!
      }
   ]
}
```

If you don't want to change the default serializer or you need to preserve the navigation property you can configure System.Text.Json serializer to preserve the references. But be careful because it changes the output structure by providing $id, $ref and **$values** properties!

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve)
```

Order example:

```
{
   "$id": "1",
   "id": "d310b004-79a2-4661-2f90-08d8d25fec03"
   "orderItems": {
      $"id": "2",
      $"values": [
         {
            $"id": "3",
            "orderId": "d310b004-79a2-4661-2f90-08d8d25fec03",
            "orderItemId": "83d36eda-ba03-448c-e53c-08d8d25fec0b",
            "orderItem": {
               "id": "83d36eda-ba03-448c-e53c-08d8d25fec0b",
               "name": "My order item"
            },
            "order": {
               "$ref": "1" // reference to the order
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and I was confused, because I had another application running the same code. The only difference was I wanted to use await this time, and in the last application I used `ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

So by removing await and adding `ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` at the end of the Async method I was able to resolve this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. Maybe you posted to the wrong question?

Comment: I got the same error "possible object cycle was detected which is not supported" but maybe my issue was different than this one.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this and I had to tell the app/context to ignore the parent entity on the child by adding the following to the **OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)** method in my db context class:

```
builder.Entity<ChildEntity>()
    .HasOne(a => a.ParentEntity)
    .WithMany(m => m.ChildEntities);
builder.Entity<ChildEntity>().Ignore(a => a.ParentEntity);
```

The last line with the **Ignore** is what did it for me.

Comment: That's quite a sledgehammer approach only to fix an object cycle in serialization. Now EF won't ever populate the navigation property.

Comment: It is brute force, but it works for me and has not had any ill effects.  If a window on your house doesn't close properly, you can install a new window or you can also make the choice to wall over it if you don't want that window in your house anymore.  The two are both perfectly valid depending on your scenario.  Downvote seems excessive as it is a viable solution, even if it is not the one you would personally choose.

Comment: Not my DV, only commented.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [JsonIgnore] annotation on your dependent attribute.

```
public class Reservation{
   public int ReservationId {get;set;}
   public int RestaurantId {get;set;}
   [JsonIgnore]
   public Restaurant Restaurant {get;set;}
}
```

https://medium.com/@panjunweide/one-notation-to-fix-object-cycle-was-detected-issue-jsonignore-dfb14f94075f

Answer (score 0):

you should try explicitly select that entity,
also I have faced with this issue and works for me,

```cs
var restaurants = await _dbContext.Restaurants
                .Include(m => m.Reservations)
                .Select(m=>new 
                    {
                        m.RestaurantId,
                        m.Name,
                        Reservations = m.Reservations
                        .Select(r=>
                        {
                            r.ReservationId,
                            r.RestaurantId
                        })

                    })
                .ToListAsync();
```