# ASP.net 6 Object Cycle was detected automapper nested list

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper

I am currently working on a personal project where I want to map the `UserTransaction` to `GetAllTransactionRes` and return all `UserTransaction` from my database when the `API/transaction` is hit. Each time I use the `API/transaction` endpoint I got this error

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectName.Modules.Transaction.Core.DTO.GetAllTransactionRes]
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.OrderedProducts.UserTransaction.TransactionId.
```

This is the `UserTransaction` Entity

```cs
    public class UserTransaction
    {
        public int TransactionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OrderedProduct> OrderedProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the `Ordered Product` Entity

```cs
    public class OrderedProduct
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public bool Returned { get; set; }

        public int TransactionId { get; set; }
        public virtual UserTransaction UserTransaction { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my mapper. `GetAllTransactionRes` and `AllOrderedProductDTO` is the exact copy of `UserTransaction` and `OrderedProduct` Entity.

```cs
CreateMap<UserTransaction, GetAllTransactionRes>().ForMember(s => s.OrderedProducts, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.OrderedProducts));
CreateMap<OrderedProduct, AllOrderedProductDTO>();
```

Since I am using MediatR. This is my handler for my `GetAllTransactionQuery`

```cs
        public async Task<ICollection<GetAllTransactionRes>> Handle(GetAllTransactionQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var Transactions = await _context.UserTransactions.Include(ut => ut.OrderedProducts).ToListAsync();
            var mapped = _mapper.Map<ICollection<UserTransaction>, ICollection<GetAllTransactionRes>>(Transactions);
            return mapped;
        }
```

Before using automapper I used the `.include` method from `efcore` which gives me the same error I searched for answers and a person commented in a StackOverflow question that i should not return DB entities directly in my API. [This is the question where the said comment is posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59199593/10973496)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `AllOrderedProductDTO` and your `GetAllTransactionRes` data transfer objects have a circular reference - transactions contains products which contain the transaction which contains the products...

Here are the DTO classes I would recommend to break out of the cycle:

```
public class GetAllTransactionRes
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    // be sure to use the products DTO here and not the entity because the entity has the loop
    public virtual ICollection<AllOrderedProductDTO> OrderedProducts { get; set; }
}

public class AllOrderedProductDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool Returned { get; set; }

    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    // do not include the transaction entity or DTO here so that we avoid the loop
    //public virtual UserTransaction UserTransaction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could even remove the transaction ID from all ordered product DTO since the products are nested inside the transaction DTO.

Comment: could ignoring UserTransation in automapper configuration resolve the issue ?

Comment: @knile - Yes, that would also work, but you would have to set an ignore any time either of those DTOs has a map configured.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. I solve this problem by adding decoration.

Reference documents:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization

```
public class OrderedProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool Returned { get; set; }

    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual UserTransaction UserTransaction { get; set; }
}
```