# How to solve: Json Exception: A possible object cycle was detected in .NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

> JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.Sliders.Company.Sliders.Company.Sliders.Company.Sliders.Company.Sliders.Company.Sliders.Company.Sliders.Company

I get an error in response, because objects contain references to each other.

Is there a way to load data without a cycled relationship?

I use these ways but do not work:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
            x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
```

or

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
           x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

or

```
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>
(options => options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

or

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x =>
```

x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

[MyError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1woD4.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using System.Text.Json, you can configure it like this.

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

You can look [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization)  and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199593/net-core-3-0-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-not-supported/59210264#59210264) to know more