# How to return FileInfo in AspNet Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to get FileInfo result from a controller but it returns always 500 .
Files exists and no error found. All middleware's and controller works fine but I don't know why i get however 500 status code.
what i Have tried is given below.

1.

```
public ActionResult GetFileinfo(string filePath) {
   FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\Mw_Prog\\Ema.txt") ;
   if(fileInfo.Exists)
     return Ok(fileInfo) ;
   else
     return StatusCode(404,"NOT FOUND");
 }
```

2. 

```
public FileInfo GetFileinfo(string filePath) {
  FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\Mw_Prog\\Ema.txt") ;
  if(fileInfo.Exists)
    return fileInfo ;
  else
    return null;
}
```

After I Checked some backgroung functionality and found Exception in RecourseInvoker.cs class.

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: "A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.Directory.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Root.Name."

Anyone Know what that means ?

Comment: Put a try-catch over 1. and check the exception message. 2. is highly unlikely to work as it doesn't expose a valid endpoint.

Comment: I did Put Try-Catch and it Works fine without Error but again it returns 500.

Comment: obviously you cannot serialize `FileInfo` ... create your own model and copy values from `FileInfo`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sending Ok() alone? Perhaps the response body (sending FileInfo) is larger than the configured limit

PD: Not reputation for adding a comment instead of answer

Comment: only ok() worked fine and i have also tried to send Kilobyte information. It seems json serialize problem. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199593/net-core-3-0-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-which-is-not-supported). if you have any suggestions, let me know

Comment: The probleem seems that FileInfo contains cycle loop properties and serialization is not allowed. You can try to serialize in a previous step using NewtonSoft and then sending the string. Or maybe you can create a class with the info that you need from FileInfo

Comment: Any example of serializing in a previous step would be helpful.

Comment: Tested. It gives error too. You cannot serialize FileInfo. Try to create another class only with the information that you need from FileInfo.

Comment: I have also tested but not possible in .Net 8.  btw THANKS!